# Loop through jQuery arrays / Output values to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a button that dynamically creates 2 inputs per click

**Data of Input 1:** string 
**Data of Input 2:** number (float) (0-100)

I am creating an array of each like this.

```
var recipe_flavour_name = $("input[name='flav-name']").map(function()  {return $(this).val();}).get();
var recipe_flavour_percent = $("input[name='flav-percent']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

As far as I can tell, the arrays are comma separated values.

Let's for simplicity's sake say:

```
recipe_flavour_name = a,b,c
recipe_flavour_percent = 5,6,7
```

I then want to take the `number value` to use in a function and then loop through all the values and use jQuery's `.html()` to add the values to a `div`.

I have tried this: `flavPercent1` is just `recipe_flavour_percent`

```
var arrayLength = flavPercent1.Length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var flavML = (flavPercent1[0] / 100 * 100 * 1000) / 1000;
    var flavGrams = (flavML * .98 * 100) / 100;
    var flavPercent = (flavML / 100 * 1E4) / 100;
    $('.live-flavours').html('<tr>'+flavName[0]+'<td></td>'+parseFloat(flavML).toFixed(2)+'<td>'+parseFloat(flavGrams).toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+parseFloat(flavPercent1[0]).toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>');
};
```

But I only get flavGrams and flavPercent returned, dynamically adding more data to the array does nothing.

**What do I want to achieve?**

- Grab the values of specified inputs in an array.
- Pass them to a function.
- Loop through the values and output them in HTML using jQuery.

I hope that makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: this questions will be easy to answer if there is a demo of the problem

Comment: I understand that but I have no demo, I can see what needs to be done, I just cannot for the life of me work out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so assuming that you don't have a problem getting the arrays you need, the problem lies within your for loop.

YOUR CODE:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
var flavML = (flavPercent1[0] / 100 * AMOUNT * 1000) / 1000;
var flavGrams = (flavML * .98 * 100) / 100;
var flavPercent = (flavML / AMOUNT * 1E4) / 100;
$('.live-flavours').html('<tr>'+flavName[0]+'<td></td>'+parseFloat(flavML).toFixed(2)+'<td>'+parseFloat(flavGrams).toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+parseFloat(flavPercent1[0]).toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>');};
```

1. You put everything in the for loop, yet make no reference to the index. I'm assuming everywhere you put [0] you actually want [i]. This means that every time the index increases, you are getting the next array element.

   2. You should use .append instead of .html. .html means that the current html will be replaced by what you are adding.
   3. Finally, although making it dynamic is possible, I'm not sure that JQuery is the best libary to use in this case. I'd suggest taking a look at libraries such as Vue or MoonJs (both are very light and very simple libraries) etc... to find a much easier, and frankly better way to do this. They allow for dynamic rendering, and what you are trying to do becomes insanely simplified.

Hope this helps.

(hopefully) WORKING CODE:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var flavML = (flavPercent1[i] / 100 * AMOUNT * 1000) / 1000;
    var flavGrams = (flavML * .98 * 100) / 100;
    var flavPercent = (flavML / AMOUNT * 1E4) / 100;
    $('.live-flavours').append('<tr>'+flavName[i]+'<td></td>'+parseFloat(flavML).toFixed(2)+'<td>'+parseFloat(flavGrams).toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+parseFloat(flavPercent1[i]).toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>');};
```

Comment: Incredible... I have spent too long in front of the screen again, coders blindness... Thanks so much for this, it was a simple fix that I overlooked, excellent work :)

Comment: BTW the HTML is wrong too! Wow.. <tr>'+flavName doesnt have a closing </tr> or even a <td>..

Comment: Using $('.live-flavours').closest( "tr" ).after( worked a treat here also